# Can't install fluent UI react in an Outlook Web add-in project

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, fluentui-react

I'm trying to install fluent UI on an Outlook web add-in project and I get different errors:

In [@fluentui/react - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fluentui/react) says I should use `npm i @fluentui/react` but I get:

```
http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/@fluentui%2ffont-icons-mdl2 337ms
silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @fluentui/font-icons-mdl2@^8.0.4 UNKNOWN: unknown error
```

In the [Release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/wiki/Version-8-release-notes) says I should use `npm install @fluentui/react@^8.0.0` and I get

```
http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/@fluentui%2freact 394ms
silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @fluentui/react@8.0.0 No matching version found for @fluentui/react@8.0.0.
```

I have no previous experience with node or react, so feel free to point even basic stuff.

I have searched for install issues but all I could find was not related to a late version of the package.
I have also tried `npm install --save @fluentui/react` getting the first mentioned error.

Edit:

I am behind a corporate proxy and this is my config:

```
[System variable]
GLOBAL_AGENT_HTTP_PROXY = http://username:password@corporate.proxy.com:port

[.npmrc]
proxy=http://username:password@corporate.proxy.com:port
https-proxy=http://username:password@corporate.proxy.com:port/
http-proxy= http://username:password@corporate.proxy.com:port
strict-ssl=false
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was editing the question to provide my proxy config I noticed a potentially unwanted slash in the https-proxy, I removed it and tried the npm install commands:

`npm install @fluentui/react@^8.0.0` > "No matching version... found"

`npm i @fluentui/react`> Worked.

I find interesting that only part of the package download failed making me think that the proxy config was ok and not worrying about it.

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Are you building the Outlook add-in to have Outlook mobile support? If yes, dif you figure out how to differentiate the UI/UX based on the OS, like iOS and Android? Since, Outlook mobile requirements are very strict wrt to the add-in

Comment: No mobile support, sorry